# How to create a QWidget with a HWND as parent?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, wxwidgets

With wxWidgets I use the following code:

```
HWND main_window = ...
...
wxWindow *w = new wxWindow();
wxWindow *window = w->CreateWindowFromHWND(0, (WXHWND) main_window);
```

How do I do the same thing in Qt? The `HWND` is the handle of the window I want as the parent window for the new QtWidget.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the create method of QWidget.

```
HWND main_window = ...
...
QWidget *w = new QWidget();
w->create((WinId)main_window);
```

Comment: QWidget::create is protected now

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the [`QWinWidget`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/qwinwidget.html) class from the [Qt/MFC Migration Framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/)?

Answer (score 0):

How about fromWinId https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qwindow.html#fromWinId

Creates a local representation of a window created by another process or by using native libraries below Qt.