# Create a QPaintDevice from HDC handle

Tags: c++, qt, gdi

I have a Windows HDC handle from an external library that I'd like to use QPainter functionality to draw on. Is there any way in Qt to create a QPaintDevice from a HDC handle?

Comment: As far as I can see, it's not possible. QWidget (which inherits from QPaintDevice) has a concept of HDC. One can get its HDC through QWidget::getDC(), but one can not set it. Internally it's stored in QWidgetPrivate::dc; in the Pimpl class of QWidget and completely unaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this:

Using the Windows API, get the HWND from the HDC.

```
HWND handle = WindowFromDC(hdc);
assert(handle != NULL);
```

Then subclass QWidget to get access to the protected member convert. Using this, create the QWidget using this member as described in this solution: [How to create a qwidget with a hwnd as parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293774/how-to-create-a-qwidget-with-a-hwnd-as-parent). In this example, I've called the subclass for QWidgetWrapper.

```
QWidgetWrapper *w = new QWidgetWrapper();
w->create((Wld)main_window);
```

Note that Wld is a typedef in Qt for "Platform dependent window identifier".

Comment: And why do you think there's a HWND associated with HDC? Have you heard about ["memory DC"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win32-Memory-DC)? It has HDC, but no window.

Comment: You're right, thus the assert. This can only work if you can assume that it's not a memory DC. It's a bad solution, but the only one I've come up with.